# After 'html' task file index.html still not exists in Gulp

Tags: configuration, gulp, task

I run simple configuration:

```
gulp.task('html', function() {
    gulp.src(config.paths.html)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.paths.dist))
        .pipe(connect.reload());
});

gulp.task('connect', function() {
    server.listen(config.port);
    lrserver.listen(config.livereloadport);
});

gulp.task('open', ['connect'], function() {
    gulp.src('dist/index.html')
        .pipe(open({ uri: config.devBaseUrl + ':' + config.port + '/'}));
});

gulp.task('default', ['html', 'open']);
```

But, the first time on 'open' task file index.html still not exists and only the second time it is created and task 'open' will execute successful. What's wrong with my configuration?

I've add a console log:

```
D:\Projects\demo>gulp
[11:01:13] Using gulpfile D:\Projects\demo\gulpfile.js
[11:01:13] Starting 'connect'...
[11:01:13] Finished 'connect' after 4.33 ms
[11:01:13] Starting 'html'...
[11:01:13] Finished 'html' after 9.03 ms
[11:01:13] Starting 'open'...
[11:01:13] Finished 'open' after 3.14 ms
[11:01:13] Starting 'default'...
[11:01:13] Finished 'default' after 9.82 μs
```

Answer (score 0):

Your tasks depends on each other. You should make 'open' depends on 'html' so ot will wait for it to finish:

```
gulp.task('html', function() {
    gulp.src(config.paths.html)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.paths.dist))
        .pipe(connect.reload());
});

gulp.task('connect', function() {
    server.listen(config.port);
    lrserver.listen(config.livereloadport);
});

gulp.task('open', ['connect', 'html'], function() {
    gulp.src('dist/index.html')
        .pipe(open({ uri: config.devBaseUrl + ':' + config.port + '/'}));
});

gulp.task('default', ['open']);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not working for me. Please, look at console log. In both cases the order is correct. What's wrong?

Comment: Try adding ./ to the start of the src path in open. Also try running only html and make sure the file exist in dist/index.html

Comment: ./ doesn't helped. I've add console.log(fs.existsSync('./dist/index.html')); to the 'open' task and it output false at the first time, but true at the second time. So, file ./dist/index.html has been created only after 'default' task.

Comment: Thanks to you and this article http://schickling.me/synchronous-tasks-gulp/ I found the solution given below. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

So, I found the solution. By default all tasks in gulp are running in parallel. So, you need the task dependency if you want to run them in series, as answered **eburger** before:

```
gulp.task('open', ['connect', 'html'], function() {
    gulp.src('dist/index.html')
        .pipe(open({ uri: config.devBaseUrl + ':' + config.port + '/'}));
});
```

But beside this you need also get gulp to know when the previous task will has been finished (added **return**):

```
gulp.task('html', function() {
    return gulp.src(config.paths.html)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.paths.dist))
        .pipe(connect.reload());
});
```

This solved my issue.